# How to fix "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8'" when loading traces files

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, trace, prefetch

I tried to implement a basic trace modeler, and the first thing is to load traces (.xz files), which are available at http://hpca23.cse.tamu.edu/champsim-traces/speccpu/

```py
import csv

with open('400.perlbench-41B.champsimtrace.xz', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    for row in csvreader:
        print(": ".join(row))
```

I expect to load these files but it showed up UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 0: invalid start byte. Do I need to do some pre-processing to these traces?

Comment: The immediate fix is to not specify in `open()` that this is a text file with an encoding when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

.xz file is a lossless data compression file by LZMA so you need to unzip file first like the code below.

```
import lzma

with lzma.open('400.perlbench-41B.champsimtrace.xz') as lzmaFile:
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
```

After that you can process it freely. Try `print(lzmaFile.read())`.

Comment: The kernel appears to have died, could I load just first few rows?

Comment: What is actually inside the file?

Comment: These are memory traces, and I want to transform them to sequences of integers.

Comment: Don't call `.read()` on large files. You can feed the `lzmaFile` object to `csv.reader()`, just like `csvfile` in the OP.

Comment: BUT you should open it in text mode: `lzma.open(..., 'rt', encoding='utf8')`. Otherwise the `csv` module will complain about receiving `bytes` instead of `str`.

Comment: Then I got the same error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 0: invalid start byte